# No suitable constructor found for entity type 'XName'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core

I have implemented EntityFrameworkcore sqlite in Xamarin forms while creation of Database the following Exception is throughing.

```
No suitable constructor found for entity type 'XName'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'ns', 'localName' in 'XName(XNamespace ns, string localName)'.
```

Comment: Search your entity classes for property of type `XName`

Comment: i have searched this XName butt  not found .please Read the exception detail .

Comment: It could also be a property of a property of a property and so on. Look for an entity class that has a property of a type that is defined outside your project. Most probably that type is under the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace, e.g. `XElement`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it stemmed from using **XElement** as a property of an EF DbSet.

**Background**

EF cannot instantiate classes which require arguments in the constructor (in your case XName).